# How can I find a broken pipe (Python unit test)?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I've written a Thread class that reads from an URL, processes the stream and keeps a result as an attribute. In unit testing, instead of an URL, a 'rb' file gets passed to the object.

I've re-factored the class to be a Process with a Queue. Running the program normally will give me the expected results, but in unit testing, I'm getting 'broken pipe' errors.

The problem is that I don't see which test is failing, so I really can't even start to debug.

```
def testThread(self):
    f = open('TestFiles/test.html', 'rb')

    q = Queue()     #One individual queue for each individual process
    myclass = MyClass(q, f)
    myclass.start()
    myclass.join()

    value = myclass.get_data()
    q.close()

    self.assertEqual(0.7628, value, value)
```

Note: the file gets closed inside the run() method.

Comment: Do you perform a `close()` on the queue once you're done with it?

Comment: @robertklep, added a q.close() after each test with the same result.

Comment: Also, what version of Python are you using? I seem to remember similar issues occuring with early versions of Python 2.6.

Comment: @robertklep, Python 3.2